# How to solve problem same command-line for different apps

Tags: command-line, package-management, php, golang

I have `deployer` for the PHP app on my machine with command `dep` to use it. Recently, I installed dependency management to develop Golang Apps called with the same command, `dep`.

I am trying to use `dep` on Golang apps but it is still calling the `dep` of PHP Deployer. I still need both of them, so removing one is not the solution I need. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What is the output of `type -a dep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is find the full command to each `dep` command. For example if PHP dep is `/usr/bin/dep` I would then alias it like this:

`alias php-dep='/usr/bin/dep`

Then I would figure out what the full command to run Golang `dep` is and then run:
`alias go-dep='/usr/local/bin/dep`

Then when I needed to reference one of these commands I could just run `go-dep` or `php-dep` and the correct command can run.

In order to find the dep commands I would do something like this

`locate dep |grep -v headers |grep -v snap |grep -v python |grep -v share`

And sort through the output until I found the locations of each.

In order to make your alias' permanent you can create the file `~/.bash_aliases` which is sourced by `~/.bashrc` or simply edit the ~/.bashrc` file directly.

These files are read when a new session is being created and will run whatever alias or command you put in them

For example I have a very basic `~/.bashrc`:

```
cat ~/.bashrc
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
if [ $TILIX_ID ] || [ $VTE_VERSION ]; then
        source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
fi
alias nano='nano -wET 4'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
PS1="\[\e[01;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[01;34m\]\w  \[\e[01;34m\]$\[\e[00m\] "
export EDITOR=nano
```

This runs every time I create a session in bash.